# Fixed position menus when using bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have been trying to learn css, html, and javascript by creating a dashboard from scratch rather than just buying a boostrap dashboard ui. However, I have come across an issue I cannot seem to figure out. I have a sidebar menu and top menu that I want to be fixed:position so they remain static on the screen however if I do that the content div shifts underneath the menus. I realize i can add margin to shift them back into place but even then if I do the toggle button to expand the sliding menu then what is the best method to shift that sideways? I have put everything in this jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/4x60gqsn/

Thanks
Shaun

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <title>Collapsible sidebar using Bootstrap 4</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS CDN -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Our Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <!-- Font Awesome JS -->
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/solid.js" integrity="sha384-tzzSw1/Vo+0N5UhStP3bvwWPq+uvzCMfrN1fEFe+xBmv1C/AtVX5K0uZtmcHitFZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/fontawesome.js" integrity="sha384-6OIrr52G08NpOFSZdxxz1xdNSndlD4vdcf/q2myIUVO0VsqaGHJsB0RaBE01VTOY" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <!-- Sidebar  -->
        <nav id="sidebar">
            <div class="sidebar-header">
                <img class="nav-logo" src="../login/images/PrintPerry.png">
                <strong>PP</strong>
            </div>

            <ul class="list-unstyled components">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
                        <span class="nav-text">
                            HOME
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
                        <span class="nav-text">
                            TEST
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <!-- Page Content  -->
        <div id="content">

            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                <div class="container-fluid">

                    <a href="#" id="sidebarCollapse">
                        <i class="fas fa-align-justify fa-lg" ></i>
                    </a>
                    <span>
                        <a href="#" class="profile-btn">
                            <i class="fas fa-user fa-lg"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" class="profile-btn">
                            <i class="fas fa-envelope fa-lg"></i>
                        </a>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <h2>Collapsible Sidebar Using Bootstrap 4</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

                <div class="line"></div>

                <h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

                <div class="line"></div>

                <h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

                <div class="line"></div>

                <h3>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery CDN - Slim version (=without AJAX) -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Popper.JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="js/sidebar.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your intention is to use `position:fixed` so that on a scroll the navbar remains in position.

This can also be achieved by using `position: sticky;` an alternative that can do the same job but more cleaner. [**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/njcoder/w0qp5s2k/3/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function() {
    $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
/*
    DEMO STYLE
*/

@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700";
body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  background: #fff;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.7em;
  color: #999;
}

a,
a:hover,
a:focus {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.navbar {
  padding: 15px 10px;
  background: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dedede;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: sticky !important;
  top: 0px;
}

.bg-light {
  background-color: #fff !important;
}

.navbar-btn {
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none !important;
  border: none;
}

.nav-side-btn {
  background-color: #282a2b;
}

.line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #ddd;
  margin: 40px 0;
}

i,
span {
  display: inline-block;
}


/* ---------------------------------------------------
    SIDEBAR STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

.profile-btn {
  float: right;
  margin: 0px 20px;
}

#sidebar {
  position: sticky;
  top: 1px;
  height: 100vh;
}

#sidebar .nav-text {
  font-weight: 500;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header img {
  width: 200px;
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header {
  text-align: center;
}

#sidebar.active .nav-text {
  display: none;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

#sidebar {
  min-width: 250px;
  max-width: 250px;
  background: #fff;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  border-right: 1px solid #dedede;
}

#sidebar.active {
  min-width: 80px;
  max-width: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}

#sidebar.active .sidebar-header h3,
#sidebar.active .CTAs {
  display: none;
}

#sidebar.active .nav-logo {
  display: none;
}

#sidebar.active .sidebar-header strong {
  display: block;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
  text-align: left;
}

#sidebar.active ul li a {
  padding: 20px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.6em;
}

#sidebar.active ul li a i {
  margin-right: 0;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#sidebar.active ul ul a {
  padding: 10px !important;
}

#sidebar.active .dropdown-toggle::after {
  top: auto;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(50%);
  transform: translateX(50%);
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header {
  padding: 20px;
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header strong {
  display: none;
  font-size: 1.8em;
}

#sidebar ul.components {
  padding: 20px 0;
  border-bottom: 0px solid #47748b;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  display: block;
}

#sidebar ul li a:hover {
  color: 282a2b;
  background: #e9e9e9;
}

#sidebar ul li a i {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#sidebar ul li.active>a,
a[aria-expanded="true"] {
  color: #fff;
}

a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 20px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

ul ul a {
  font-size: 0.9em !important;
  padding-left: 30px !important;
}

ul.CTAs {
  padding: 20px;
}

ul.CTAs a {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.9em !important;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

a.download {
  background: #fff;
  color: #7386D5;
}

a.article,
a.article:hover {
  background: #e9e9e9 !important;
  color: #fff !important;
}


/* ---------------------------------------------------
    CONTENT STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

#content {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.content-wrapper {
  padding: 20px;
}


/* ---------------------------------------------------
    MEDIAQUERIES
----------------------------------------------------- */

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #sidebar {
    min-width: 80px;
    max-width: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: -80px !important;
  }
  .dropdown-toggle::after {
    top: auto;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(50%);
    transform: translateX(50%);
  }
  #sidebar.active {
    margin-left: 0 !important;
  }
  #sidebar .sidebar-header h3,
  #sidebar .CTAs {
    display: none;
  }
  #sidebar .sidebar-header strong {
    display: block;
  }
  #sidebar ul li a {
    padding: 20px 10px;
    font-size: 1.3em;
  }
  #sidebar ul li a span {
    font-size: 0.85em;
  }
  #sidebar ul li a i {
    margin-right: 0;
    display: block;
  }
  #sidebar ul ul a {
    padding: 10px !important;
  }
  #sidebar ul li a i {
    font-size: 1.3em;
  }
  #sidebar {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  #sidebarCollapse span {
    display: none;
  }
  #sidebar .nav-logo {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

  <title>Collapsible sidebar using Bootstrap 4</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS CDN -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Our Custom CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

  <!-- Font Awesome JS -->
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/solid.js" integrity="sha384-tzzSw1/Vo+0N5UhStP3bvwWPq+uvzCMfrN1fEFe+xBmv1C/AtVX5K0uZtmcHitFZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/fontawesome.js" integrity="sha384-6OIrr52G08NpOFSZdxxz1xdNSndlD4vdcf/q2myIUVO0VsqaGHJsB0RaBE01VTOY" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <!-- Sidebar  -->
    <nav id="sidebar">
      <div class="sidebar-header">
        <img class="nav-logo" src="../login/images/PrintPerry.png">
        <strong>PP</strong>
      </div>

      <ul class="list-unstyled components">
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
            <span class="nav-text">
                HOME
              </span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
            <span class="nav-text">
                TEST
              </span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <!-- Page Content  -->
    <div id="content">

      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container-fluid">

          <a href="#" id="sidebarCollapse">
            <i class="fas fa-align-justify fa-lg"></i>
          </a>
          <span>
              <a href="#" class="profile-btn">
                <i class="fas fa-user fa-lg"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="profile-btn">
                <i class="fas fa-envelope fa-lg"></i>
              </a>
            </span>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <div class="content-wrapper">
        <h2>Collapsible Sidebar Using Bootstrap 4</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

        <div class="line"></div>

        <h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

        <div class="line"></div>

        <h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

        <div class="line"></div>

        <h3>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- jQuery CDN - Slim version (=without AJAX) -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Popper.JS -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="js/sidebar.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So position sticky seems to work. If i apply that same positioning to the navbar on the top as well why does it not remain static/fixed also like the sidebar? I was hoping to get both the top menu and the sidebar menus fixed. Thanks for your help and pointing out that property because I have not seen that actually.

Comment: you need to use `position: sticky !important;`, have updated the code, please check

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you so much! Just curious for a learning perspective. Is this considered the cleanest way to do this or would using translatex on the content div the best method?

Comment: Is IE a target browser? `position:sticky` will not work in IE and there is only partial support in Edge.

Comment: sticky postion is not widespeardly supported.  https://caniuse.com/#search=sticky

Answer (score 1):

If you want to support all of the browsers, do [the bootstrap way](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/examples/navbar-fixed/). Give body as much padding-top as the height of the header and padding-left as much as the width of the sidebar. For both the header and sidebar, use positin-fixed. Suppose if  header has a  60px height, set body's padding-top to 60px.

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

.width-100px {
  width: 100px;
}

.fixed-left {
  left: 0;
}

body {
  padding-top: 56px;
  padding-left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header class="fixed-top">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
<aside class="position-fixed fixed-left bg-danger width-100px h-100">

</aside>
<main class="container-fluid bg-primary text-white">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <p>
        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum fugiat delectus, ea vitae iure reprehenderit quaerat, mollitia ipsam id qui nesciunt, officiis corporis quod! Aspernatur est velit exercitationem unde fuga.</span>
        <span>Explicabo incidunt sed aspernatur accusamus, mollitia repellendus aperiam minus inventore pariatur velit a necessitatibus libero eligendi molestiae magni nesciunt culpa vero exercitationem! Illum iure ratione eveniet dolore. Quo, officia earum?</span>
        <span>Pariatur quo quae deserunt sunt assumenda ipsa cupiditate maiores doloremque non explicabo consequuntur mollitia, enim fuga, laudantium consequatur minima, similique libero soluta ipsam distinctio. Sunt impedit expedita iste eveniet nam.</span>
        <span>Obcaecati soluta optio, reiciendis repellendus nostrum, recusandae quis placeat, provident officia vitae a. Voluptas explicabo earum, dolor et, sed excepturi perferendis nobis hic doloribus sint optio culpa tempora aspernatur ratione!</span>
        <span>Officiis totam placeat dolor, accusamus eaque sequi nulla cumque magni! Quisquam earum vitae accusamus vero eligendi harum a sunt, mollitia omnis laboriosam assumenda error sed tempore excepturi animi similique architecto?</span>
        <span>In amet eligendi aliquam sunt optio provident eius illum dolorum repellendus rem accusamus, quis beatae atque at quos excepturi ut facilis quibusdam incidunt magnam! Dolores et optio odio blanditiis enim!</span>
        <span>Totam nisi itaque ipsam aperiam dolores distinctio, sint facere quia enim, ab neque fugiat laudantium quis quam quo libero consectetur omnis tenetur possimus tempora eligendi quos! Ut quas ex ullam!</span>
        <span>Illum, minima. Repellendus debitis unde officiis tempora voluptas, modi cupiditate, blanditiis numquam quibusdam, expedita voluptatem aliquid ipsum alias. Eius, pariatur ipsa commodi in fugit doloremque atque optio laudantium soluta culpa.</span>
        <span>Eveniet commodi facilis fugiat autem sunt! Necessitatibus est ipsum consequuntur quidem, quia fugit tempore consequatur ullam veniam eius excepturi consectetur itaque unde maiores vitae, error beatae ipsa ea? Neque, commodi!</span>
        <span>Aperiam, officia aspernatur? Accusamus, quo. Corporis necessitatibus enim, omnis, voluptates tenetur harum optio quam repudiandae ea suscipit, commodi asperiores illum pariatur quidem nobis et. Modi quisquam dolorum earum unde laboriosam?</span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: So for this method I would just need to make a toggle event then to adjust the padding to the collapsed sidebar?

Comment: @IrishRedneck  Yes